# Materialize Checkbox Return Value

Tags: checkbox, materialize

Im using the checkbox inside a form, as shown below.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="blunch" />
      <label for="blunch">Burrito Lunch</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="trip" />
      <label for="trip">Ski Trip</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dance" />
      <label for="dance">Snowball Dance</label>
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg waves-effect waves-light" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

when i try to see what the output is when a checkbox is checked, it only shows up as a question mark. Is there a way to figure out what name the result is?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by `name of result`? Checkbox can only have boolean `checked` property.

Comment: i mean if the method is get, what will it display in the bar? @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: because right now it goes from
file:///C:/Users/Abhi/Documents/material-design-template/www/index.html
to
file:///C:/Users/Abhi/Documents/material-design-template/www/index.html?

Answer (score 2):

`name` attribute is used to label the fields in the message send to a server with an `HTTP` (Hyper-Text Transfer Protocol) `GET` or `POST` when you hit submit in a form. You have to give `name` to the input fields through `name` attribute. You've given `id`s that's why you're facing problem.

**Check this Code**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="blunch" name="blunch" />
        <label for="blunch">Burrito Lunch</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="trip" name="trip" />
        <label for="trip">Ski Trip</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="dance" name="dance" />
        <label for="dance">Snowball Dance</label>
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg waves-effect waves-light" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```